# ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url doesnt generate hashed version in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I got an constants.rb file in config/initializers with the following content:

```
DEFAULT_IMAGES  = {
  profile: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('v2/default_profilepic.jpg'),
  banner: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('v2/profile-banner.jpg'),
  missing: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('v2/missing.png'),
}
```

When I try to call DEFAULT_IMAGES somewhere in the code or even in the console then I get the images back without the hash. Is it that what its supposed to do and am I wrong in my expectations?

DEFAULT_IMAGES
=> {:profile=>"http://localhost:3000/assets/v2/default_profilepic.jpg", :banner=>"http://localhost:3000/assets/v2/profile-banner.jpg", :missing=>"http://localhost:3000/assets/v2/missing.png"}

I would expect something like this "/assets/v2/missing-d38d4bdbf9f2cf313e346a844de298c0.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also give Proc a try

```
proc { ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('v2/missing.png') }.call
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your code into an after_initialize block within your specific environment file or in application.rb:

```
config.after_initialize do
  DEFAULT_IMAGES  = {
    profile: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('v2/default_profilepic.jpg'),
    banner: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('v2/profile-banner.jpg'),
    missing: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('v2/missing.png'),
  }
end
```

Drawback is that you'll need to reference your constant through the namespace of your application:

```
Foo::Application::DEFAULT_IMAGES
```

Answer (score 0):

```
config.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

Add this line to application.rb and check in rails console.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix

```
DEFAULT_IMAGES  = {
  profile: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('v2/default_profilepic.jpg'),
  banner: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('v2/profile-banner.jpg'),
  missing: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('v2/missing.png'),
}
```

You need to use `*_path`, not the `*_url` as per your expected data.

[`image_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_path) : Computes the path to an image *asset*.